# Use two Uniforms in Vertex Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, buffer, shader, uniform

was following the OpenGL RedBook and was able to use a Uniform for a frustrum or translate matrix. I have become a little lost trying to use both at the same time.

```
//Declarations
GLfloat frustum[4][4] = {
    {((2.0*frusZNe //Etc...
GLfloat translate[4][4] = {
    {1.0, 0.0,     //Etc...
```

And then I use it in Init:

```
GLuint uboIndex;
GLint uboSize;
GLuint ubo;
GLvoid *buffer;

uboIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "frustumUniform");
glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(program, uboIndex, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE, &uboSize);
buffer = malloc(uboSize);

const char* frustumName[1] = {"frustum"};

GLuint indices[1];
GLint size[1];
GLint offset[1];
GLint type[1];
glGetUniformIndices(program, 1, frustumName, indices);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, indices, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, offset);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, indices, GL_UNIFORM_SIZE, size);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, indices, GL_UNIFORM_TYPE, type);

//memcpy(&buffer + 0, &frustum, sizeof(frustum));

glGenBuffers(1, &ubo);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboSize, &frustum, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboIndex, ubo);
```

Immediately afterwards, I do the same thing for the translate one but change some of the values, such as: glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "translateUniform");

```
///Translate Uniform, same 20 statements as above, with alterations
GLuint uboIndex2;
GLint uboSize2;
GLuint ubo2;
GLvoid *buffer2;



uboIndex2 = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "translateUniform");
glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(program, uboIndex2, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE, &uboSize2);
buffer2 = malloc(uboSize2);

string offsetString = iToS(uboIndex2);
debugMsg(offsetString + "Index2, 1:");

const char* translateName[1] = {"translate"};

GLuint indices2[1];
GLint size2[1];
GLint offset2[1];
GLint type2[1];

glGetUniformIndices(program, 1, translateName, indices2);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, indices2, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, offset2);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, indices2, GL_UNIFORM_SIZE, size2);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, indices2, GL_UNIFORM_TYPE, type2);

//memcpy(&buffer + 0, &frustum, sizeof(frustum));



glGenBuffers(1, &ubo2);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo2);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboSize2, &translate, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboIndex2, ubo2);

string uboIndex2S = iToS(uboIndex2);

debugMsg("Index 2: " + uboIndex2S);

string uboSizeS, uboSizeS2, uboIndexS, uboIndexS2;

uboSizeS = iToS(uboSize);
uboSizeS2 = iToS(uboSize2);
uboIndexS = iToS(uboIndex);
uboIndexS2 = iToS(uboIndex2);


debugMsg(uboSizeS + " ," + uboSizeS2 + " ," + uboIndexS + " , " + uboIndexS2);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 430 core



uniform frustumUniform {
    mat4 frustum;
};

uniform translateUniform {
    mat4 translate;
};

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
void
main()
{

vec3 trans = vec3(.2, 0, 0);

mat4 view = mat4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -200.0, 1.0);

mat4 rotate = mat4(0.2, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        -0.3, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 1.0);


mat4 translateOld = mat4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);



gl_Position = frustum * translate * view * vPosition;
}
```

It compiles, but the second Uniform no longer works. Any ideas?

Comment: Where you do the same thing for the translate, does that include creating the UBO? So you have separate UBOs for the two uniforms?

Comment: perhaps you should also post the code for the translateUniform.

Comment: @RetoKoradi  and MuertoExcobito , done.

Comment: That's not exactly your vertex shader... you've hand-picked the lines where you declare the uniform blocks, but the GLSL compiler/linker may strip those declarations away depending on the whether the actual final shader program makes use of them. To that end, sometimes you'll loose a uniform or vertex attribute in the final linked program because while the vertex shader computes something with it, no later stage (e.g. geometry, fragment, tessellation) uses the result and OpenGL eliminates it.

Comment: More to the point, to debug uniform / vertex attribute issues on StackOverflow, you usually need to include more parts of the shader including any code branches that use the variable and often the other shaders. It's possible the compiler just stripped the uniform block away completely because it wasn't used - in which case the location would come back **-1**. _Your code spits out these locations, can you include the output in the question?_

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman , etc Vertex shader posted in entirety. Forgot about shader compilation output. Have much more confidence in finding the issue now. Will examine and potentially find the problem once I re-gain access to test environment.